# jQuery DataTable custom language url works, but loader doesn't

Tags: jquery, datatables, loader, custom-url

Is it possible in `jQuery dataTable` to add loader when it has a custom language url?
For example:

```
"language": 
  {          
    "processing": "<span style="width:100%;"><img src="http://www.snacklocal.com/images/ajaxload.gif"></span>",
     "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
  }
```

When I have both it doesn't work, but if i comment url line, loader works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33323/how-to-put-image-in-loading) article and I sent message to DataTable forum, and they sad:

> This is something that is going to be added in for v2 of DataTables, which is in progress, but slowly.
>
> Until then you would need to load the Ajax language information using $.getJSON (or similar) and then merge it into your local object as needed, then using the result in the DataTable configuration

**UPDATE:**
I comment my source line and added text manually like this:

```
        "language": {
         // "sUrl": "../HTMLRepository/JsLocalization/DataTableLocalization_Serbian.json"
        "sEmptyTable": "Ni jedan podatak ne postoji za zadate kriterijume",
        "sInfo": "Prikaz _START_ do _END_ od ukupno _TOTAL_ redova po strani",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Prikaz 0 do 0 od ukupno 0 redova",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrirano od ukupno _MAX_ redova)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sInfoThousands": ",",
        "sLengthMenu": "Prikaz _MENU_ redova",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Molimo sačekajte, učitavanje u toku...",
        "sSearch": "Pretraži:",
        "sZeroRecords": "Podaci se ne podudaraju",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": "Prva",
            "sLast": "Poslednja",
            "sNext": "Sledeća",
            "sPrevious": "Predhodna"
        }          
    },
```

And in $(document).ready function i have

```
$('#patientsTable').on('processing.dt', function (e, settings, processing) {
    if (processing) {
        activateLoader();
        activateOverlay();
    }
    else {
         deactivateLoader();
         deactivateOverlay();
   }
```

And finally it works :)
Thanks a lot @Shiladitya

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
"language": 
    {          
    "processing": "<span style='width:100%;'><img src='http://www.snacklocal.com/images/ajaxload.gif'></span>",
     "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `ES6 template literals`

```
"language": 
  {          
    "processing": `<span style="width:100%;"><img src="http://www.snacklocal.com/images/ajaxload.gif"></span>`,
    "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
  }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No errors. But if I comment line with url, loader works.
I made some function like this,

    $('#patientsTable').on('processing.dt', function (e, settings, processing) {
        if (processing) {
            activateLoader();
            activateOverlay();
        }
        else {
            deactivateLoader();
            deactivateOverlay();
        }
    }).dataTable();
But it works just when i don't have custom language url... Any suggestion?

Comment: @Dacke I think it should be `"language": { "sUrl": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json" }`

Comment: @Dacke Did you put the `jQuery` code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: No, because I have find() function which create this table.

Comment: @Dacke Wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`.